# Blazor assembly: Data is updated but Ui is not refreshed

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, mudblazor

I'm brand new to blazor ( about 1 months). Now I'm using BlazorHero as the template to build an Spa app.

In one of my pages, Data is updated but Ui is not refreshed. Strangely, I can refresh the Ui by programmatically press the "reload" key (manually clicking the button works as well).
Code here:

```
private MudButton _reloadButton;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    //...
    await GetDataAsync(); //It works here.
    //...
}

private async Task GetDataAsync()
{
    _sourceId2RecordCounts = (await LibAdaHub.AdaPPM.DataSources.GetSourceId2MeasureRecordCounts(Config.AdaHubUrl)).Value!;
    _dataRecords = (await LibAdaHub.AdaPPM.DataRecords.GetAll(Config.AdaHubUrl, _sourceId)).Value!;
 //When I stepped into here, the data are really updated.
}

private async void CreateOrEdit(string sourceId, string recordId)
{
    var dialog = _dialogService.Show<CreateDialog>(Localizer["DataSources"],
        new DialogParameters
        {
            {nameof(CreateDialog.SourceId), sourceId},
            {nameof(CreateDialog.RecordId), recordId},
            {nameof(CreateDialog.Model), string.IsNullOrEmpty(_sourceId) 
                ? null : _dataRecords.FirstOrDefault(i => i.SourceId == _sourceId)},
            {nameof(CreateDialog.ModelType), typeof(DataRecord)}
        },
        new DialogOptions
        {
            CloseButton = true,
            FullScreen = true,
            DisableBackdropClick = true
        });
    var result = await dialog.Result;
    if (result.Cancelled)
    {
        return;
    }

    // await GetDataAsync(); //Data are updated by ui is not refreshed!
    await _reloadButton.OnClick.InvokeAsync(null); //But this works and the Ui freshed.
}
```

and in the blazor:

```
<MudTable Hover="true" Elevation="25" Items="_dataRecords" Dense="true" Bordered="false" Striped="true" 
          Filter="new Func<DataRecord, bool>(Search)">
 ...
                <MudButton DisableElevation Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" 
                           OnClick="async () => await CreateOrEditAsync(_sourceId, _recordId)"
                           StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.AddComment" IconColor="Color.Surface">
                    @Localizer["Create"]
                </MudButton>
                 <MudButton @ref="_reloadButton" DisableElevation Variant="Variant.Filled" OnClick="GetDataAsync" 
                       StartIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Refresh" IconColor="Color.Surface" 
                       Color="Color.Secondary" Style="margin-left: 5px;">@Localizer["Reload"]</MudButton>
```

Although I can get the job done by introducing the _reloadButton, but it looks veired. Any idea? Thanks!

2023-7-4： I just added the code of calling CreateOrEdit() in the second piece of code.

Comment: Try adding a `await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` at the end of your method.

Comment: At first glance `private async void CreateOrEdit(string sourceId, string recordId)` looks the culprit.  This almost certainly should be `private async Task CreateOrEdit(string sourceId, string recordId)`.  Also [by convertion] call it `CreateOrEditAsync`.  I can't see where you using it, so can't be sure.  If it is I'll explain why.

Comment: @HH Yes! You are both right. I added the code calling AddOrEdit and answered my question myself. But pls post an answer and I will mark it as the right one.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, and I did renamed it to ~~Async. This should keep it more meaningful. Thanks~

Comment: Actually that Async post-fix was mainly useful when async was introduced, and a lot of APIs had to support old and new versions of functions. In my work we stopped using it a few years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does appear to be the `async void`. That breaks the normal update flow.

Try this:

```cs
//private async void CreateOrEdit(string sourceId, string recordId)
  private async Task CreateOrEdit(string sourceId, string recordId)
  {
       ... as before

       await GetDataAsync();   // ought to work now
    // await _reloadButton.OnClick.InvokeAsync(null);
  }
```

Comment: Yes this works! Sorry I'm late because I suffered an internet problem these days. Does "async void" really means something? Vs / Copilot / Resharper give no error/warning/suggestions about it.

Comment: `async void` is fire-and-forget, it's mainly a kludge to add async support to old-style events. In Blazor you should need it only very rarely. For instance when handling a Timer event.